# Indexing a string within a class, Python tells me I'm indexing the class directly?

Tags: python, class, oop, indexing

This is the code that gives me the problem. The error I'm receiving states that "'Fraction' object does not support indexing" at line 8, even though the Fraction object is a string? Where am I going wrong?

```
class Fraction: 
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.fraction_str = str(x) + '/' + str(y)

    def add(self, second_fraction):
        our_fraction = self.fraction_str
        if second_fraction[-1] != our_fraction[-1]:
```

Comment: can you please paste the entire traceback of the error code you see?

Comment: Is `second_fraction` also of class `Fraction` or is it an actual string? If it's the former, maybe you want `second_fraction.fraction_str[-1]` instead.  It's hard to tell because you've given us no code to actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: Which line is line 8?

Comment: `second_fraction` must be a string as @rayryeng asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I think your problem is that our_fraction is a string but second_fraction is an object of type Fraction and not a string.

Comment: Thank you. Yup, it was just me being dumb. Fixed it by adding second_fraction = second_fraction.fraction_str under the def. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely due to `second_fraction` being of class `Fraction` where your syntax is assuming it is a string.  Actually access the `fraction_str` variable in the class itself:

```
if second_fraction.fraction_str[-1] != our_fraction[1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confused here. Your `Fraction` class *is not* a string. Your `Fraction` class is using [*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) not [*inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)). A `Fraction` instance *stores a string as a data field*, the instance its self *is not a string*.

From the exception Python is rasing, `second_string` seems to be a `Fraction` class and you're trying to index it. This won't work, since `Fraction` is not a string. You need to accesses the string that the `Fraction` instance contains:

```
if second_fraction.fraction_str[-1] != our_fraction[-1]:
    # code ...
```

*If*, you want your `Fraction` class to support indexing, you could overload the built-in method which corresponds to the index operator `[]`, `__getitem__`:

```
class Fraction:
    # code...
    def __index__(self, slice):
        return self.fraction_str[slice]
```

Be careful here though. `Fraction` still is not a string. It is simply a class that supports indexing on its instances.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you are calling the Class object directly and expecting it to return the `Fraction.fraction_str` object.

The best way is to reference the class object like this: `second_fraction.fraction_str[-1]`

Or you can write a `__getitem__` method